# Fail a build when the post-build event of a referenced project fails

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2019, post-build-event

I have a winforms app (PostBuildApp) that has a project reference to another project (PostBuildLib) inside the same solution. Both projects have a post-build event. When the post-build event of the Lib fails Visual Studio keeps on compiling and running the post-build event of the App which is dependent on the Lib. Is there a way to fail a build when the post-build event of one of the referenced projects fails?

[Screenshot of visual studio succeeding a build when post-build of a referenced project failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOEiY.png)

Update: to be clear, I'm rebuilding the PostBuildApp project. Not running it. I've found this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/6733) which might be related?

Comment: What is `Option -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> "On Run..."` set to? You can set it to `Do not launch`.

Comment: I mean, if the dependency fails and no older version can be used, then the other Project cannot build, so both fail.

Comment: @Jimi "On run, when projects are out of date:" is set to "Always build" and "On run, when build or deployment errors occur" to "Do not launch". Just to be clear, I'm not running/launching. This problem occurs when I rebuild the App.

Comment: Debugging, before you Run, you need to Build. So Build comes before Run. And you don't Run if you cannot Build. I have these same settings: when a dependency is not built, all Projects that have that dependency fail the build.

Comment: De build of the App is not failing in my case, Visual Studio says the build succeeded, which is not entirely true because its dependency failed the post-build event. The post-build of the App should only run when the build is successful.

Comment: @Icarus, It seems Visual Studio will continue to build the project(PostBuildApp) if the PostBuildLib project had successfully been built before VS checked and built post-build event. And I think it is not possible to fail a(next) build if you only add commands in post-build events in Visual Studio.